# Download older XAMPP on Linux without Browser

Tags: debian, xampp

I am connected to a Unix Server via ssh and want to install xampp on this server.

How do I download / install an older Version of xampp (1.7.7) without having access to a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wget` to get what you want from the server.

Answer (score 1):

you can issue this command in shell:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.7.7/xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz
```